# test to see if HiveServer2 metastore is working correctly

Tags: apache, postgresql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I recently upgraded our cluster's HiveServer to HiveServer2.  I also set up the Hive Metastore (in remote mode) and moved away from embedded mode (which we were previously running).

I want to test that things are properly configured and that the metatdata is acutally being stored in the remote metastore.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  Are their certain logs I could check to verify this behavior?

I am afraid things are not configured correctly, and I am still running my metastore in local mode, as when I query the postgresql database on the machine hosting the metastore, there are no rows in the metastore DB (despite the fact that I have created test tables through beeline).

It might be worth mentioning is that the end goal of this is to be able to query data stored in HDFS via SparkSQL.  Do I need HiveServer2 to accomplish this?  Apologies, I am new to a lot of this technology.

Here is my hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://w7/metastore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>password</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://w7:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
   <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>mn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>mn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.zookeeper.namespace</name>
    <value>hive_zookeeper_namespace_hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.MemoryTokenStore</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
    <description>Enable Hive's Table Lock Manager Service</description>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```